# How to replace string using regex

Tags: notepad++

I have an XML file which includes tags
I need to add an attribute to the tag

```
<names>abc</names>
```

will become

```
<names name="abc"></names>
```

I have no idea how to work with regex
and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<(\w+)>(.+?)(?=</\1>)`
- Replace with: `<$1 name="$2">`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<(\w+)>         # openning tag and tag name captured in group 1
(.+?)           # group 2, content of tag
(?=             # positive lookahead, make sure we have efter:
  </\1>         # closing tag, \1 is a backreference to group 1 (i.e. the tag name
)               # end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1 (i.e. tag name)
$2          # content of group 2 (i.e. tag content)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
<names name="abc"></names>
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for the explanation. Saved me a lot of work!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `<(?!/).*?>` to match all `<...>` except  tag. To match a particular tag, you can replace the `.*` in the regular expression.

I am not sure if `notepad++` supports regular expression matching. If it doesn't, you can use `sublime text`'s regular expression to match and findAll to update.

Comment: How is this answering the question?